# Golang: verify that string is a valid hex string?

Tags: string, go, validation, hex

I have a struct:

```
type Name struct {
    hexID string
    age uint8
}
```

What is the easiest way to check that `hexID` field is a valid hex string? And if not - rise an error.

For example:

```
var n Name
n.hexID = "Hello World >)" // not a valid hex
n.hexID = "aaa12Eb9990101010101112cC" // valid hex
```

Or maybe there are somewhere struct `tag` exists?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about this one

```
regexp.MatchString("[^0-9A-Fa-f]", n.hexID)
```

True if string contains HEX illegal characters

Comment: this one also works, hmm I'm completely confused now which one to use :(

Answer (score 2):

Iterate over the characters of the string, and check if each is a valid hex digit.

```
func isValidHex(s string) bool {
    for _, r := range s {
        if !(r >= '0' && r <= '9' || r >= 'a' && r <= 'f' || r >= 'A' && r <= 'F') {
            return false
        }
    }
    return true
}
```

Testing it:

```
fmt.Println(isValidHex("Hello World >)"))
fmt.Println(isValidHex("aaa12Eb9990101010101112cC"))
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://go.dev/play/p/I8aqvUIfE5T)):

```
false
true
```

Note: you'd be tempted to use [`hex.DecodeString()`](https://pkg.go.dev/encoding/hex#DecodeString) and check the returned error: if it's `nil`, it's valid. But do note that this function expects that the string has even length (as it produces bytes from the hex digits, and 2 hex digits forms a byte). Not to mention that if you don't need the result (as a byte slice), this is slower and creates unnecessary garbage (for the gc to collect).

Another solution could be using [`big.Int.SetString()`](https://pkg.go.dev/math/big#Int.SetString):

```
func isValidHex(s string) bool {
    _, ok := new(big.Int).SetString(s, 16)
    return ok
}
```

This outputs the same, try it on the [Go Playground](https://go.dev/play/p/x7zAJive25c). But this again is slower and uses memory allocations (generates garbage).

Comment: Thank you for quick response! Isn't there any already builtin solution in Go for such cases? Like Python has `hex(string)` ?

Comment: Hmmm `hex.DecodeString()` seems to be weird if it is only working with even chars in a string, I don't want to rely on length, I only want to pass a string and then check if its valid or not without worrying about anything else

Comment: @armaka See edited answer. There's solution in the standard lib, but it does other things, so it's slower and generates (memory) garbage.

Comment: I think the best for me is to use the first answer you posted, however @ojacomarket also have advised some `regex` stuff, which also works, now I'm really confused which one to use :(

Comment: @armaka You may use any of them. The regexp solution is likely slower.

Answer (score 2):

> Comment: I'm completely confused now which one to use :( – armaka

---

Different inplementations have different performance. For example,

```
func isHexRock(s string) bool {
    for _, b := range []byte(s) {
        if !(b >= '0' && b <= '9' || b >= 'a' && b <= 'f' || b >= 'A' && b <= 'F') {
            return false
        }
    }
    return true
}

func isHexIcza(s string) bool {
    for _, r := range s {
        if !(r >= '0' && r <= '9' || r >= 'a' && r <= 'f' || r >= 'A' && r <= 'F') {
            return false
        }
    }
    return true
}

var rxNotHex = regexp.MustCompile("[^0-9A-Fa-f]")

func isHexOjacoGlobal(s string) bool {
    return !rxNotHex.MatchString(s)
}

func isHexOjacoLocal(s string) bool {
    notHex, err := regexp.MatchString("[^0-9A-Fa-f]", s)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    return !notHex
}
```

Some benchmark results:

```
BenchmarkRock-4         36386997    30.92 ns/op     0 B/op   0 allocs/op
BenchmarkIcza-4         21100798    52.86 ns/op     0 B/op   0 allocs/op
BenchmarkOjacoGlobal-4   5958829   209.9 ns/op      0 B/op   0 allocs/op
BenchmarkOjacoLocal-4     227672  4648 ns/op     1626 B/op  22 allocs/op
```

Comment: would you prefer code performance over code readability? In this case you should use C or Assembler :D

Comment: @ojacomarket: I don't have to choose between readability and performance. By design, Go is both readable and performant. As the saying goes, "Some people, when confronted with a problem, think 'I know, I'll use regular expressions.' Now they have two problems." My benchmarks show that your regular expression solution (OjacoLocal) is massively more expensive than my Go solution (Rock). That matters when operating at Google scale.

Answer (score 0):

I think ParseInt method can also tackle this -

```
    _, err := strconv.ParseInt("deadbeef", 16, 64)
    if err != nil {
       fmt.Println("not a hex string")
    } else {
    fmt.Println("it is a hex string")
  }
```

Comment: Note that this doesn't work for hexadecimal strings longer than 16 digits, because that would overflow (u)int64.